# trying to understand C++ code, reading a file

Tags: c++

```
float process(float Beta, std::ifstream & INPUT, float mass, float energy, int Juse = 1, int Jerror = 1, int intype = 1)
{
    float crosscons = 8 * M_PI * mass * mass / energy; //Creates a constant that is used to calculate the cross section

    int dwarf_count = 0;
    int dcol = 0;
    string line;
    string item;
    int header = 0;
    string skip("#");
    INPUT.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while (getline(INPUT, line)) {
        if (contains(line, skip))
        {
            header++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

This first bit I know it's reading a file, but I have no idea where it's reading the file or where it gets it from. Inside the function I know it's trying to skip to the data because it looks like the file is filled with `#`
I'm really new to C++ so i'm sorry if this really simple and stupid. Anything helps thanks!

Comment: `INPUT` is passed into the function as an already open file. You'd need to look where `process` is being called from. Can't comment on code I can't see. Consider a [mcve].

Comment: Start with `std::ifstream & INPUT` and go from there. [Decent books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) helps.

Comment: Short answer - you're looking in the wrong place.  This code doesn't care where the file is.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea where it's reading the file

The call to `INPUT.seekg()` is seeking the `INPUT` stream's read pointer to the beginning of the file, and then the `getline()` loop is reading individual lines of text from the stream until the end of the stream is reached, or a line not containing `#` is found, whichever occurs first.

> or where it gets it from

The `process()` is getting the `INPUT` stream from the caller as an input parameter. Where the caller is getting the stream from, we can't answer that, as there is not enough code shown.  You need to look at the code that is calling `process()` to know where the `INPUT` stream is coming from.